# CryBlend error: "There is more than one Texture of type diffuse. Please correct that and try again"

Tags: export, add-on, external-applications

I want to export a plant with the [CryBlend Addon](http://www.cryblend.com/). In Blender are 2 Textures applied to the model. When I click on export it always returns the following error:

> "There is more than one Texture of type diffuse. Please correct that
>   and try again"

[image]

Is there any solution for it?

Comment: Welcome Littlejofel :) Please start with the tour: http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour, for a solid answer you could also upload your file, see this meta post: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/630/announcing-blend-exchange-a-new-solution-to-blend-hosting. Anyway, enjoy blender.se!